# What is the best way to use Optional with null check in Java?

Tags: java, java-8

I am having a variable (testvariable) according to the isNull of the variable I need to make a method call as below

```
if (testvariable != null) 
    method(testvariable);
 else 
    method();
```

What is the best way to simplify the code in Optional

Comment: Optional isn't designed to avoid or replace null checks. Your code is absolutely fine.

Comment: `Optional.ofNullable(testVariable).ifPresentOrElse(this::method, this::method)` (but it's not what Optional is for)

Comment: Please leave your code like it is, and do not use Optional for this.  Optional is not meant to be a replacement for `if`.  Part of being a good programmer is knowing how to write the most readable code possible, so that others can work with it once you are no longer available.

Answer (score 4):

Given that your `method` function returns a value (is not `void`), you can use the `map` and `orElseGet` functions, like this:

```
return Optional.ofNullable(testVariable)
    .map(tv -> method(tv))
    .orElseGet(() -> method());
```

The `map` function transforms your optional to contain the return value of `method`, but only if the optional contains a value. If `testVariable` was null, then the result will be retrived from the function passed to the `orElseGet` method.

If `method` returns `void`, then don't use `Optional`. `Optional` is best used to model the presence or absence of a *value*.

Comment: what if the method call is `void`, the `return` would not make any sense

Comment: Mind that the OP asked about a way to *simplify* the code…